# Creating XML document in jQuery environment

Tags: jquery, xml, creation

Have referred to JQuery docs where they mention this piece of code.

```
var xmlDocument = [create xml document];
 $.ajax({
 url: "page.php",
 processData: false,
 data: xmlDocument,
 success: handleResponse
 });
```

but i am trying to make the same request in Adobe AIR environment its giving a parse error.

Is there any specific way of creating an xml Document using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all

I have got  a plugin at [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/createXMLDocument) location

Answer (score 0):

in order for the server to get the data, you need to say

```
data: "varname=" + xmlDocument,
```

otherwise the data has no variable name on the other side of the transmission.

Comment: FYI, you could also do this: data: {varname:xmlDocument}